# How to randomly generate really small numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

Suppose I want to draw a random number in the range [10^-20, 0.1], how do I do that?

If I use numpy.random.uniform, I don't seem to go lower than 10^-2:

```
In [2]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[2]: 0.02506361878539856

In [3]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[3]: 0.04035553250149768

In [4]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[4]: 0.09801074888377342

In [5]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[5]: 0.09778150831277296

In [6]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[6]: 0.08486347093110456

In [7]: np.random.uniform(0.1, 10**(-20))
Out[7]: 0.04206753781952958
```

Alternatively I could generate an array instead like:

```
In [44]: fac = np.linspace(10**(-20),10**(-1),100)

In [45]: fac
Out[45]: 
array([  1.00000000e-20,   1.01010101e-03,   2.02020202e-03,
         3.03030303e-03,   4.04040404e-03,   5.05050505e-03,
         6.06060606e-03,   7.07070707e-03,   8.08080808e-03,
         9.09090909e-03,   1.01010101e-02,   1.11111111e-02,
         1.21212121e-02,   1.31313131e-02,   1.41414141e-02,
         1.51515152e-02,   1.61616162e-02,   1.71717172e-02,
         1.81818182e-02,   1.91919192e-02,   2.02020202e-02,
         2.12121212e-02,   2.22222222e-02,   2.32323232e-02,
         2.42424242e-02,   2.52525253e-02,   2.62626263e-02,
         2.72727273e-02,   2.82828283e-02,   2.92929293e-02,
         3.03030303e-02,   3.13131313e-02,   3.23232323e-02,
         3.33333333e-02,   3.43434343e-02,   3.53535354e-02,
         3.63636364e-02,   3.73737374e-02,   3.83838384e-02,
         3.93939394e-02,   4.04040404e-02,   4.14141414e-02,
         4.24242424e-02,   4.34343434e-02,   4.44444444e-02,
         4.54545455e-02,   4.64646465e-02,   4.74747475e-02,
         4.84848485e-02,   4.94949495e-02,   5.05050505e-02,
         5.15151515e-02,   5.25252525e-02,   5.35353535e-02,
         5.45454545e-02,   5.55555556e-02,   5.65656566e-02,
         5.75757576e-02,   5.85858586e-02,   5.95959596e-02,
         6.06060606e-02,   6.16161616e-02,   6.26262626e-02,
         6.36363636e-02,   6.46464646e-02,   6.56565657e-02,
         6.66666667e-02,   6.76767677e-02,   6.86868687e-02,
         6.96969697e-02,   7.07070707e-02,   7.17171717e-02,
         7.27272727e-02,   7.37373737e-02,   7.47474747e-02,
         7.57575758e-02,   7.67676768e-02,   7.77777778e-02,
         7.87878788e-02,   7.97979798e-02,   8.08080808e-02,
         8.18181818e-02,   8.28282828e-02,   8.38383838e-02,
         8.48484848e-02,   8.58585859e-02,   8.68686869e-02,
         8.78787879e-02,   8.88888889e-02,   8.98989899e-02,
         9.09090909e-02,   9.19191919e-02,   9.29292929e-02,
         9.39393939e-02,   9.49494949e-02,   9.59595960e-02,
         9.69696970e-02,   9.79797980e-02,   9.89898990e-02,
         1.00000000e-01])
```

and pick a random element from that array, but wanted to clarify anyway if the first option is possible since I could be probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Actualy I don't know python but the logic is same every language. Generate random number between 10^10 and 10^11 then divide it to 10^12

Comment: I think you're missing the statistics of your problem... with a uniform distribution, the chance of hitting a number 10^-20 is vanishingly small. Do you want a log distribution instead?

Comment: Thats a cool idea! I just tried numpy.random.lognormal with an arbitrary mean and sigma and I get very low values. Finding the right value for these arguments is something though.

Comment: @jkrish: Note that the distribution will be heavily biased. Do you want a uniform distribution or do you want highly probable low values?

Comment: Uniform distribution in the range [0.1, 10^-20]. I guess Alex's answer of setting the low, very low works best!?

Comment: @jkrish: It seems that `uniform()` sorts the arguments. The highest argument is `high`, the lowest is `low`, regardless of their position.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Cool! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Aaron: You're right. `min(np.random.uniform(10**(-20), 0.1) for _ in range(10000000))` returns a number around `1E-9`.

Comment: @jkrish: Actually, from the doc "If high < low, the results are officially undefined and may eventually raise an error, i.e. do not rely on this function to behave when passed arguments satisfying that inequality condition."

Comment: @EricDuminil  Meaning I stick to: rand[min, max]?

Comment: Yes. But `min` should be lower than `max`, which isn't the case in your example.

Answer (score 11):

You need to think closely about what you're doing. You're asking for a uniform distribution between almost 0.0 and 0.1. The average result would be 0.05. Which is exactly what you're getting. It seems you want a random distribution of the exponents.

The following might do what you want:

```
import random

def rnd():
    exp = random.randint(-19, -1)
    significand = 0.9 * random.random() + 0.1
    return significand * 10**exp

[rnd() for _ in range(20)]
```

The lowest possible value is when `exp=-19` and `significand=0.1` giving `0.1*10**-19 = 1**-20`. And the highest possible value is when `exp=-1` and `significand=1.0` giving `1.0*10**-1 = 0.1`.

Note: Technically, the `significand` can only aprach 1.0 as `random()` [is bounded to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) [0.0, 1.0), i.e., including 0.0, but excluding 1.0.

Output:

```
[2.3038280595190108e-11,
 0.02658855644891981,
 4.104572641101877e-11,
 3.638231824527544e-19,
 6.220040206106022e-17,
 7.207472203268789e-06,
 6.244626749598619e-17,
 2.299282102612733e-18,
 0.0013251357609258432,
 3.118805901868378e-06,
 6.585606992344938e-05,
 0.005955900790586139,
 1.72779538837876e-08,
 7.556972406280229e-13,
 3.887023124444594e-15,
 0.0019965330694999488,
 1.7732147730252207e-08,
 8.920398286274208e-17,
 4.4422869312622194e-08,
 2.4815949527034027e-18]
```

See "[scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)" on wikipedia for definition of significand and exponent.

Answer (score 5):

As per the numpy documentation:

low : float or array_like of floats, optional
Lower boundary of the output interval. All values generated will be greater than or equal to low. The default value is 0.

With that in mind, decreasing the value of `low` will produce lower numbers

```
>>> np.random.uniform(0.00001, 10**(-20))
6.390804027773046e-06
```

Comment: You're not decreasing `low`, you're decreasing `high`. Values won't be higher than `1E-5`, and you'll never reach `0.1`

Comment: @EricDuminil with `numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)` as the function definition, that is decreasing low surely?  Also from the docs: "If high < low, the results are officially undefined and may eventually raise an error, i.e. do not rely on this function to behave when passed arguments satisfying that inequality condition."

Comment: @NickA: Yes, the order should be reversed. Still : `max(np.random.uniform(0.00001, 10**(-20)) for _ in range(10000000))` returns `9.999999414469333e-06` so it looks like `0.00001` is interpreted as `high`.

Comment: This answer does not span [10^-20, 0.1] it is limited to [10^-5, 10^-6]. Also, I'm surprised this didn't throw an error. Since `high` is set lower than `low`. "If high < low, the results are officially undefined and may eventually raise an error, i.e. do not rely on this function to behave when passed arguments satisfying that inequality condition." ]https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html

Comment: I now see in the comments, that it was intended for the arguments to be in reverse. Then the solution will be functional, but is still limited to [10^-20, 10^-5] with an average of about 0.5*10^-6. It will likely never see anything below 10^-7. That said, OP seems fine with it.

Answer (score 3):

How about generating a random number between 1 and 10 000, 
then divide that number by 100 000.

Comment: This was my immediate thought, although it wouldn't be between 1 and 10000, it would be numbers between `1` and `1e19` divided by `1e20`

Comment: This is the wrong answer if you ever want to actually span [10^-20, 0.1], and get the really low numbers. If using a uniform distribution, this will mostly generate numbers around 0.05 (the mean), as OP already has. You will never see numbers like 10^-19 or 10^-20.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen True, but forcing the number to move towards 10^-20 and 0.1 is then not random

Comment: @NickA It is perfectly random. Just not uniformly random. OP asked for numbers in the range [10^-20, 0.1], which implies that some of the results should approach the lower bound in orders of magnitude. If not, there is no point in setting such a lower bound.

Comment: Might as well chuck `return 0.05` in a function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to keep a uniform distribution and avoid problems related to float representation, just draw 20 integers uniformly between 0 and 9 and "build" your result with base 10 representation (you'll still have a uniform distribution):

```
result = 0
digits = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
for idx,digit in enumerate(digits):
  result += digit*(10**idx)
```

This will give you a number between 0 and 10**19 -1. You can just interpret the result differently to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The likelyhood of a random number less than 10^-20 arising if you generate uniform random numbers in the range [0,0.1] is one in 10^-19. It will probably never happen. However, if you *have* to make sure that it *cannot* happen (maybe because a smaller number will crash your code), then simply generate your uniform random numbers in the range [0,0.1], test them,  and reject any that are too small by replacing them with another uniform random number out of the same generator and re-testing. This replaces "very unlikely" by "certain never to happen".

This technique is more commonly encountered in Monte-Carlo simulations where you wish to randomly sample f(x,y) or f(x,y,z) where the coordinates (x,y[,z]) must be within some area or volume with a complicated definition, for example, the inside of a complex mechanical component. The technique is the same. Establish bounding ranges [xlow, xhigh], [ylow, yhigh] ... and generate a uniformly distributed random coordinate within this bounding box. Then check whether this random location is within the area / volume to be sampled. If not, generate another random tuple and re-check.